# Turning on Enhanced E-Commerce for Firebase GA project

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Currently working on switching from using GA Legacy SDK to Firebase SDK in our mobile app. Overall been going great, except it looks like enhanced e-commerce doesn't work out of the box.

I'm using "ecommerce_purchase" event, but not able to pass actual purchased items to GA, only get item count. Here is the code I'm using, it's in C# since we use Xamarin:

```
    public void LogTransaction(OrderStatus order, Basket basket)
    {
        if (_firebaseAnalytics == null)
            return;

        var products = new List<IParcelable>();
        foreach (var product in basket.Products)
        {
            products.Add(CreateProductBundle(product));
        }

        var transactionBundle = new Bundle();
        transactionBundle.PutParcelableArrayList("items", products.ToArray());
        transactionBundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.TransactionId, order.Id);
        transactionBundle.PutDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Value, (double)order.Total);
        transactionBundle.PutDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Tax, (double)basket.SalesTax);
        transactionBundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Currency, "USD");
        transactionBundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Coupon, basket.Coupon?.CouponCode);

        _firebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.EcommercePurchase, transactionBundle);
    }

    private Bundle CreateProductBundle(BasketProduct basketProduct)
    {
        var product = new Bundle();
        product.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemId, basketProduct.ProductId.ToString());
        product.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemName, basketProduct.Name);
        product.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemCategory, string.Empty);
        product.PutDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Price, (double)basketProduct.BaseCost);
        product.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Currency, "USD");
        product.PutLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Quantity, basketProduct.Quantity);

        return product;
    }
```

Looking at this [google doc](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/enhanced-ecommerce) I can do it with GTM. However, there is 0 documentation out there as to how to set up GTM tag for Google Analytics (Firebase).

There is plenty of info on how to do it for Google Analytics - Universal Analytics, but that's not an option for mobile apps any longer, since I don't have access to  Google Analytics Tracking ID.

Anyone figured out a way around this mess? Or more specifically does anyone have a link to a good tutorial that would help me set-up "ecommerce_purchase" tag in GTM. 
[image]

Comment: Enhanced ecommerce expects the products as an array with the key of "items". How do you pass your products?

Comment: @bseh yep that's exactly how I'm doing it. Will add the code I'm using to the original question.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? Having the same issue, also using Xamarin.